# Does WPF .net core 3.1 run on WOA?

Tags: c#, wpf, arm

I come from `VB.Net` and recently switched to `C#`. I'm using WPF with .net core 3.1. When I compile, C# creates a .dll file with the same name as the .exe. Normally this would be fine but when I go to use the "Windows Application Packaging Project" to create an ARM64 based installer, it throws a warning that the.dll it's referencing (the one created when compiling) is a mismatch and only x86. If I try to create a 64bit installer, it does the exact same thing. I've tried everything and cannot get this to allow me to build the app with anything besides x86. Does anyone know if this is normal and if compiling a WPF .net core app would even run natively on WOA?

Comment: Use [**Publish**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/publishing-with-visual-studio) function to create an `exe` for target platform.

Comment: I double checked and this is the old way to publish that doesn't allow you to submit to the windows app store. I'm using the "Windows Application Packaging Project" to publish my app for the store.

Comment: Yet another [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/desktop/desktop-to-uwp-packaging-dot-net). And **Publish** in .NET Core is pretty new functionality, a different one to .NET Framework.